# Android alternative for Swift Package Manager?

Tags: android, git-submodules, swift-package-manager, modularization

I am working on creating a modularised app. I had been using git submodules, but AFAIK, Swift Package Manager (SPM) in iOS works as a wrapper around git submodule. Can you please suggest Android alternative for it so that I don't have to  use git submodules directly?

I had been looking at CMake, but not sure if it will fulfil the purpose.